# If statements end function early if false in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Assuming pos_of_xy (x, y) n is already defined to return an int, this code segment exits once one of the if statements returns false as if they were nested. I need them all to run regardless of the previous if statements. I'm not sure what I am forgetting.

```
let final = ref [] in begin
  if x < (size-1) then let pos = pos_of_xy (x+1, y) size in final := pos::!final;
  if y < (size-1) then let pos = pos_of_xy (x, y+1) size in final := pos::!final;
  if y > 0 then let pos = pos_of_xy (x, y-1) size in final := pos::!final;
  if x > 0 then let pos = pos_of_xy (x-1, y) size in final := pos::!final;
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of describing the problem is that `let` is stronger than `if`. A `let` takes a sequence of statements after `in`, and your subsequent `if`s are treated as part of this sequence. Things should work if you parenthesize each `let`:

```
if x < size - 1 then
    (let pos = pos_of_xy (x + 1, y) size in final := pos :: !final);
```

Or you could do without the `let`:

```
if x < size -1 then final := pos_of_xy (x + 1, y) size :: !final;
```

As a side comment, the code might look even nicer to an FP progammer if you wrote in a more functional style (without the mutable value).

**Update**

Here's a quick sketch of a more functional way to calculate your list:

```
let good (x, y) = x >= 0 && x < size && y >= 0 && y < size in
let topos (x, y) = pos_of_xy (x, y) size in
let goodxy =
    List.filter good [(x + 1, y); (x, y + 1); (x - 1, y); (x, y - 1)] in
List.map topos goodxy
```

Comment: Thank you! How could this be done in a more functional style? I don't need an exact answer but maybe a starting point.

Comment: More generally, unless the expression in the `then` (or `else`) branch is really trivial, it can't hurt to put it inside parentheses (or `begin ... end`), so that you don't have to ask yourself questions about OCaml's precedences.

Comment: @AndrewM you can do it that way: `let l = [] in let l = if cond then x::l else l in let l = ... in l` (the first and last local bindings being optional except for the sake of regularity of the pattern).

Comment: Or, put another way, `let` has lower precedence than `if`

Answer (score 1):

As Jeffrey Scofield said, `let` has lower precedence than `if`. So it's as if you wrote:

```
let final = ref [] in begin
  if x < (size-1) then (let pos = pos_of_xy (x+1, y) size in (final := pos::!final;
  (if y < (size-1) then (let pos = pos_of_xy (x, y+1) size in (final := pos::!final;
  (if y > 0 then (let pos = pos_of_xy (x, y-1) size in (final := pos::!final;
  (if x > 0 then (let pos = pos_of_xy (x-1, y) size in (final := pos::!final;)))))))))))
end;
```

You can look at the table of precedences [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec116) (scroll up a little). As you can see, `if` has higher precedence than `;`, which has higher precedence than `let`.